# What i miss with the translation from matlab to R?

Tags: matlab

I want to implement the following matlab code into R (with some changes in variables) but it doesn't work.Can someone (a good translator!!!) help me please?

Here is the matlab code:

```
% Define domain
dx = 0.001;
L = pi;
x = (-1+dx:dx:1)*L;
n = length(x); nquart = floor(n/4);
% Define hat function
f = 0*x;
f(nquart:2*nquart) = 4*(1:nquart+1)/n; f(2*nquart+1:3*nquart) = 1-4*(0:nquart-1)/n;
plot(x,f,’-k’,’LineWidth’,1.5), hold on
% Compute Fourier series
CC = jet(20);
A0 = sum(f.*ones(size(x)))*dx;
fFS = A0/2; for k=1:20
A(k) = sum(f.*cos(pi*k*x/L))*dx; % Inner product B(k) = sum(f.*sin(pi*k*x/L))*dx;
fFS = fFS + A(k)*cos(k*pi*x/L) + B(k)*sin(k*pi*x/L);
plot(x,fFS,’-’,’Color’,CC(k,:),’LineWidth’,1.2) end
```

And my effort in R:

```
dx = 0.01
L = 2
x = seq(-L,L,dx)
n = length(x)
y = floor(n/4)
f = rep(0,n)

a = 0
b = y;b
c = y*2;c
d = y*3;d
e = n;e

f[a:b] = 0
f[b:c] = 1
f[c:d] =-1
f[d:e] = 0

A0 =  sum(rep(f,n)) *dx ;A0
fFS = A0/2
m = 100
Am = numeric(0)
Bm = numeric(0)
for (i in 0:m){
  Am[i] = sum(f * cos(pi*(i)*x/L) ) * dx 
  Bm[i] = sum(f * sin(pi*(i)*x/L) ) * dx 
  Fou  = fFS + Am[i] *cos((i)*pi*x/L) + Bm[i] *sin((i)*pi*x/L)
  }


plot(x,f,type="l",col="blue")
lines(x,Fou,type="l",col="orange")
```

Why my code doesn't work?

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is not nearly enough. It’s as if I said “it’s dark in here”. Should I switch the light on, open the blinds, wait till morning, open my eyes, get out of the septic tank, or what? We’d need at least to see some error messages. Otherwise you’re asking people to copy-paste your code into R Studio, which may be a step too much to ask sometimes.

Comment: my apologies.there is no error messages just different result.sorry for the inconv

Comment: Look carefully. Your inputs are different. E.g. `dx` is an order of magnitude different, `L` is totally different (2 vs pi), etc. You ideally want to open up both scripts in their respective IDEs - i.e. in the Octave IDE, as well as in R Studio. Then look at the values of all the variables/objects - there will be differences that are due to either typos or due to different behavior of the functions you use. Your goal will be to make them both the same. It's infinitely easier when you're looking at the table of variables displayed by the IDE! Check it out.

Comment: Please don’t make assumptions about the gender of users, unless their user name is unequivocally gendered. There is no indication in “Unslander Monica” of the gender of this user. “Monica” here refers to someone else, the user name is a statement.

Comment: didn't know .thank you chris my man

Comment: i was joking.For the rest i totally agree.Good luck with the greek language

Answer (score 1):

Thank you  Unslander Monica for your motivation and power.If you ever visit Athens Greece i will offer you a coffee

```
dx = 0.01
L = 2*pi
x = seq(0,L+dx,dx)
n = length(x);n 
y = floor(n/4);y

f = rep(0,length(x));f

a = 0
b = y;b
c = y*2;c
d = y*3;d
e = n;e

f[a:b] = 0
f[b:c] = 1
f[c:d] = 1
f[d:e] = 0
f
A0 =  sum(f * rep(1,n)) *dx*2/ L
fFS = (A0/2) * rep(1,length(f))

n = 100
for(i in 1:n){
  Am = sum(f * cos((2*pi*(i)*x)/L)) * dx*2 / L
  Bm = sum(f * sin((2*pi*(i)*x)/L)) * dx*2 / L
  fFS = fFS  +  Am*cos((2*(i)*pi*x)/L) + Bm*sin((2*(i)*pi*x)/L)
}
plot(x,f,type="l","col"="blue")
lines(x,fFS,type="l","col"="darkorange")
```